# Custom text to the left of the left margin

Tags: margins, indentation, marginpar

I'd like to write some custom text (e.g. "hello world" in grey) to the left of the left margin, and it should follow the same spaces amongst the lines and should have the same font and size of the text inside the margin. Example (| is the left margin):

Hello | bla bla bla

world | bla bla bla

---

EDIT: I used marginpar, but an undesired indentation appears ("Notare" should be aligned with "unita"):

[image]

The settings of the geometry package are the following:

```
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            right=1cm,
            bottom=1.25cm,
            bindingoffset=0.5cm,
            marginparwidth=15mm
            ]{geometry}
```

Example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            right=1cm,
            bottom=1.25cm,
            bindingoffset=0.5cm,
            marginparwidth=15mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
$\textcolor{Magenta}{\bullet}$ Questa condizione è vera se si considerano i task $\tau_j$ che condividono risorse  con altri task, altrimenti non avrebbe senso parlare di $\mu_j \left( R_k \right) > n_k$ (numero di unità della risorsa condivisa $R_k$, richiesta dal task $\tau_j$, maggiore del numero di unità attualmente disponibili della risorsa condivisa $R_k$).
\\
\reversemarginpar
\marginpar{\textcolor{Grey}{Cosa mia}}
Notare che allora il task $\tau_j$ è bloccato sulla risorsa condivisa $R_k$ per cui sarebbe più preciso dire che, quando $\mu_j \left( R_k \right) > n_k$, si ha che $n_k = 0$ (pag. 236 Buttazzo inglese). Quindi sarebbe più corretto scrivere ($P$ è la probabilità):

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you think about using `\marginpar`? It should of course be redefined to print in gray.

Comment: Hello @Ivan, thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and the words are printed out of the page. I need something which is able to adjust itself according to the sides and the margins of the page. I'm using these customized margins: \usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.25cm,right=1cm,bottom=1.25cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}

Comment: You need a `%` to close the line:
`\marginpar{\textcolor{Grey}{Cosa mia}}%`

Comment: Perfect @Ivan, now it works well